# Akka Stream Graph parallelisation

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, akka-stream

I've created a `Graph` whcih contains a `Balance`. This `Balance` distributes the load over 5 `Flows`. What I expected what would happen was that every instance of my `Flow` would run on a seperate `Thread`. However, this is not what happens.
When I'm printing the `Thread` name I notice that all `Flows` are being executed on the same `Thread`.

The code I'm using is:

```
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
val in = Source(1 to 10)
  val out = Sink.ignore

  val bal = builder.add(Balance[Int](5))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](5))

  val f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = Flow[Int].map(x => {
    println(Thread.currentThread())
    x
  }).async

  in ~> bal ~> f1 ~> merge ~> out
  bal ~> f2 ~> merge
  bal ~> f3 ~> merge
  bal ~> f4 ~> merge
  bal ~> f5 ~> merge

  ClosedShape
})
```

This outputs:

> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]

My expectation was that the output would be something along the lines of:

> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4,5,main]
>
> Thread[Stream_PoC-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]

How can I change this code sample so that the `Flows` are being executed in parallel?

Comment: This [link](http://blog.akka.io/streams/2016/07/06/threading-and-concurrency-in-akka-streams-explained) might be relevant

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that page a lot of times. However, what they do there is not what Im trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The async directive does not guarantee your stages will be executed in a separated thread. As long as the stages do not overlap in time, they might run on the same thread.

For your specific case, the executed steps might be the following:

- merge requests an element on the 1st inlet
- balance serves an element through the 1st flow
- merge requests an element on the 2nd inlet
- balance serves an element through the 2nd flow
- etc.

Now if you change your Balance as follows

```
val bal = builder.add(Balance[Int](5, waitForAllDownstreams = true))
```

You will be forcing 5 threads to be spawned, as the steps would be

- merge requests an element on 1st inlet
- merge requests an element on 2nd inlet
- merge requests an element on 3rd inlet
- merge requests an element on 4th inlet
- merge requests an element on 5th inlet
- balance starts serving elements through all flows

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. I'll try this when I get the chance. Thanks!